# AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus, pymodbus

I have some trouble trying to get info from a device using the following code:

```py
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

# mbClient = ModbusClient(method = "rtu", port="COM4", stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8, parity = 'N', baudrate = 9600)
mbClient = ModbusClient(method = "rtu", port="COM4")
mbClient.connect()

totalEnergy = mbClient.read_holding_registers(0x0000, 2, unit=1)
print(totalEnergy.registers)
mbClient.close()
```

It shows the error I put in the title.
The `0x0000` address should be the hour day etc according to the manual.
[Here you can see the hour address that appears in the manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Unv.png)

Thanks and I wish to have luck finding a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below instead of `print(totalEnergy.registers)` + enable Modbus `logging`, to dealing with Modbus error throwing:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


# Your code body ...


if not totalEnergy.isError():
    '''isError() method implemented in pymodbus 1.4.0 and later'''
    print(totalEnergy.registers)

else:
    # Do stuff to error handling.
    print('Error message: {}'.format(totalEnergy))
```

---

And check `mbClient.connect()` return and its input arguments.

These are all of the things which you could manage it on client-side.

Thus, check your Modbus server/slave side also.