# pymodbus does not read registers

Tags: serial-port, connection, decoding, modbus, pymodbus

I am developing a program to read Modbus data via serial RTU using pymodbus.

My purpose is to read data from an [ABB XRCG4 Xseries flow computing PC](https://library.e.abb.com/public/4012e1c90e4541ecb1f99ece52fe60d6/2106001MNAA.pdf). I know that the COM port on the device side is COM1 and the serial protocol is RS232, on my PC, using a [serial converter](https://www.cti-shop.com/en/rs485-converter/usb-485-mini-op) I am trying to connect to it.
I know the configuration as follows:

PROTOCOL= 'rtu'

USB_PORT = 'COM4'

PARITY = 'None'

BAUD_RATE = 9600

TIMEOUT = 3

For test purposes I made an Arduino board into a Modbus Slave. I can read the data from the board with QModMaster, Modbus Pool and SimplyModbusMaster but I am unable to do so with my script. For the board I am unable to read anything at all, not eve with the programs mentioned above.

When I use the above mentioneds program to read data from the Arduino, everything works fine, when I try with my script, I get the **AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'**

I also noticed that I get this error if I unplug the cable while connection is running.

What am I missing?  My guess is that I might not have a hardware dealer for the dsrdtr exchange, according to [page 24 of the pymodbus documentation](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/master/pdf/) or maybe on the board side, the Register Format is not ok for my code.

Here you can see the details from the ABB board

[Port description part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsx0D.jpg)

[Port description part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69MQG.jpg)

My code:

```py
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.client.sync import *
from pymodbus.register_read_message import *
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadBuilder
from pymodbus.compat import iteritems
from pymodbus.exceptions import *
import time

import logging
import logging.handlers as Handlers

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

USB_PORT = 'COM4'
PARITY = 'N' #'N'
BAUD_RATE = 9600
TIMEOUT = 0.15


client = ModbusClient(method='rtu',
                  port=USB_PORT,
                  stopbits=1,
                  bytesize=8,
                  parity=PARITY,
                  baudrate=BAUD_RATE,
                  timeout=TIMEOUT, )



while True:

    connection = client.connect()
    #print(client.)
    print(f"COM Details {client.socket}")
    #client.socket.setRTS(True)
    print(f"Connection status is: {connection} \nClient State: {client.state} \nTimeout: {client.timeout}")
    #print(client.get_serial_settings)

    try:
        #################################### CITIM INPUT REGISTER (adresa,nr de registrii si unit ID
        input_value = client.read_input_registers(count=0x01,address=10,unit=0x01)
        #client.socket.setRTS(False)
        print(input_value)
    
        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(input_value.registers, byteorder=Endian.Little)
        decoded = {
            'string': decoder.decode_string(8),
            'float': decoder.decode_32bit_float(),
            '16uint': decoder.decode_16bit_uint(),
            'ignored': decoder.skip_bytes(2),
            #'8int': decoder.decode_8bit_int(),
            'bits': decoder.decode_bits(),}

        ############### CITIM HOLDING REGISTER  (exemplu, modelul vantilatorului)
        holding_values = client.read_holding_registers(0xD1A5,6,unit=0x01)


        holding_decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(holding_values.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big)
        holding_decoded = {
            'string': holding_decoder.decode_string(8),
            #'float': holding_decoder.decode_32bit_float(),
            #'16uint': holding_decoder.decode_16bit_uint(),
            'ignored': holding_decoder.skip_bytes(2),
            #'8int': holding_decoder.decode_8bit_int(),
            'bits': holding_decoder.decode_bits(),
        }
        print("-" * 60)
        print("INPUT REGISTERS:")
        print("-" * 60)
        print(f"\nResponse: {input_value.registers} \nInput Registers Decoded values: \n")
        for name, value in iteritems(decoded):
            print ("%s\t" % name, value)
        print(f"\n Decoded speed: {decoded['float']}")
        print(f"Holding values registers:\n {holding_values.registers}")
        print("-" * 60)
        print("Holding Values Decoded Data")
        print("-" * 60)
        for name, value in iteritems(holding_decoded):
            print ("%s\t" % name, value)


    except ConnectionException as e:
        print(f"USB Disconnected {e}")

    time.sleep(2)
    client.close()
```

Comment: Check for errors as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57935155/11810946) and [this example](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/synchronous_client.html). Knowing what the actual error is will help diagnose the issue (once you have it please update your question; ideally make it a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) i.e. a single call to a `read_` function without all of the unnecessary code).

Comment: *"the serial protocol is RS232"* -- But you post a URL for a USB-RS**485** converter.  RS-485 is half duplex, whereas RS-232 is typically full duplex, plus other differences.  Is your remote device misconfigured?  And/or miswired?