# Python code for Modbus RTU gives an fault

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, modbus, rs485, pymodbus

I have four energy meters which are connected to Modbus RTU and RS485/USB converter for Raspberry PI and use Python.The system for usage at home to logging solar, home, heat and grid energy and upload to mysql.

The code works fine **EM24** at all addresses.

But the problem arises with the **DME** which gives the answer `Illegal Address`

I usage:

CARLO GAVAZZI - **EM24** - works fine

LOVATO - **DME** D301 MID - gives answer `Illegal Address`

Both connections with controlled pc software "LOVATO Xprss and Carlo Gavazzi OPC" and works fine.

USB/RS485 QinHeng CH340 serial converter

I am using Python 3.9.2 on Raspberry PI.

Can someone help, is there a mistake in the code or the LOVATO all address is locked?

example with 2 meters

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=1, stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8,  parity='N', baudrate= 9600)

W1=client.read_holding_registers(58, 1, 1)  # DME ACTIVE POWER 
W2=client.read_holding_registers(40, 1, 2)  # EM24 ACTIVE POWER

W1= W1.registers[0] / 10
W2= W2.registers[0] / 10

print(W1)
print(W2)
```

answers:

LOVATO **DME** D301 MID
`Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalAddress)`

CARLO GAVAZZI **EM24**
`ReadHoldingRegistersResponse (1)`

Comment: Please try `read_holding_registers(58, 2, 1)` and  `read_holding_registers(57, 2, 1)` (the reading is over two registers and some units will only let you read full measures; also physical vs logical addressing). For testing it's probably best to remove all other devices (this may confuse things if you don't have unique slave IDs).

Comment: I got the answer `W1= W1.registers[0]` = "0".  I tried `W1= W1.registers` the answer `[0, 22993]` then decode `decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result, Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Little)` and `print ("Hz: %0.2f" % decoder.decode_32bit_float())` = "Hz: 5312840185413632.00" but the answer should be somewhere **50** ?

Comment: Why have you assumed the data is a float (Modbus devices return data in all kinds of wonderful formats :-))? Check the manual (the manual I saw says W/100 so its probably a long which you need to divide by 100 the get the value - a common config) and [this converter](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) can be useful to see a range of possible interpretations...

Comment: `W1= W1.registers[1] / 100` and that's all :D Thanks!

Comment: Just be a little careful, the value may overflow the first register so you should also take the second one into account.

Comment: Small problem with the code when I read the first address `L1A1 = client.read_input_registers(address=7, count=2, unit=1);` and `L1A1 = L1A1.registers[1]` I get the right answer when I read second address `L1A2 = client.read_input_registers(address=7, count=2, unit=2);` and `L1A2 = L1A2.registers[1]` I get error "AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'" I can't solve it! some ideas?

Comment: Use `isError` as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57935155/11810946) i.e. `if L1A2.isError():`.

Comment: Interesting. I tried L1A2.isError() a few times, i got some errors but then started working, no errors. I only added a 1sec time break.