# Secure panel meter Elite 440-446 Type-D3B using python. (#Modbus RTU)

Tags: modbus, pymodbus, modbus-rtu-over-tcp, smartmeter

I want to know the starting address and number of registers/Count required. I am sharing screenshot below having little bit of my code and error it is generating.
[image: screenshot of error and code].

Some of the libraries I'm using in my code -

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient   
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException   
from bitstring import BitArray.
```

1. I want to know the output when I use the command print(`AllReg`) in the code given above.
2. I want to know the starting address and no. of registers/count so that I can vary starting address that is 0x64 and no. of register=0x70 in order to get correct output `AllReg=client.read_holding_registers(0x64 , 0x70, unit=3)`

Comment: Please check for errors as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57935155/11810946) and add details (note that the error you show does not appear to match the code shown). Please also copy/paste your code as text [instead of using a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11810946).